# Solving $ 20I - 0.1092 \times \ln{\left(\frac{I}{0.002}\right)} = 7 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have come across the first usage of a logarithm since college in solving a circuit equation, and I cannot remember for the life of me how to solve log problems. What I have thus far is:

$$
20I - 0.1092  \times \ln{\left(\frac{I}{0.002}\right)} = 7
$$

I think I need to raise both sides to `e`, but hoping someone could give me a basic refresher on how to do this.

Comment: I suspect you won't be able to solve this analytically however it is possible to do so numerically. To convince you this kind of problem has no analytic solution (at least no such solution in terms of the usual functions one is introduced to in calculus), consider this similar problem: $x-ln(x)=1$, if you put this into wolfram alpha your solution is in terms of the analytic continuation of the product log function.

Comment: @mathew -- I see. What level of math would you need to actually solve this, or is this not solvable outside of numerical approximation?

Comment: @David542 This is a similar case to the Lambert W-function (look it up and try to see how it's a similar thing). It is not possibly to easily compute the solution, but if this is for a circuit equation an approximation is fine. If you know calculus you can use Newton's method - otherwise use a calculator and hit find intersection of the LHS (as a function) and the function y=7.

Comment: @RobinAldabanx -- thanks, so would that be covered in a course such as complex analysis, or where would I be likely to learn more about that?

Comment: You shouldn't disdain numerical solutions, you should rejoice in analytic ones.  I haven't studied the W function, so to me it seems like giving a name to something so you pretend to understand it.  Analytic solutions are valuable because you can carry them over to other parts of the problem and they represent some real understanding of what is going on.  If I see a solution that uses sine functions, I know a lot about the sine and it tells me something about the character of the solution.  For many equations that is not available.

Comment: How accurate are the constants in your equation?  Is $0.002$ a number that could be in the range $0.0015-0.0025?$  In contrast, $0.1092$ has four places.

Comment: @David542 Math is very nonlinear. You will learn about Newton's Method in a standard Calculus I class. You can also learn it on your own, as I did - "Paul's Online Notes" is a great resource. Complex Analysis will not have virtually anything to do with this - that discipline is primarily pure mathematics, where people do not spend much time on numerical solutions. As for learning about the Lambert W-function, it's not a focus of any class, and it really isn't necessary to understand this problem. Suffice it to say that no, you cannot solve this analytically, and instead you must approximate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David, just follow along. I'm going to use variable names for your constants, though, per a fine comment below this answer.

So please find for the following development, these variables: $R=20\:\Omega$, $\eta\;V_T=0.1092\:\text{V}$, $I_0=2\:\text{mA}$, and $V_\text{CC}=7\:\text{V}$. $\eta$ is the emission co-efficient and represents the non-ideality as charges pass through a depletion region. $V_T=\frac{k\;T}{q}$ and is the statistical thermal voltage. $R$ is a resistor in series with the diode. And $I_0$ is a reference current against which $I$ is compared for these purposes. Finally, $V_\text{CC}$ is the applied voltage to the series circuit.

That said, I think the OP got a sign wrong in the equation provided. But I'm taking it as given rather than attempt to correct it. It really should be the KVL equation, $V_\text{CC} - R\;I - \eta\;V_T  \cdot \ln{\left(\frac{I}{I_0}\right)} = 0\:\text{V}$. (See Note below.)

(For those not versed in the units used in electronics for the OP's question, please forgive my use of variables with units here. They do apply, though. So I'm keeping them. Dimensional analysis still applies, of course.)

$$\begin{align*}
R\;I - \eta\;V_T  \cdot \ln{\left(\frac{I}{I_0}\right)} &= V_\text{CC}\\\\
\frac{R\;I}{\eta\;V_T}-\frac{V_\text{CC}}{\eta\;V_T} &= \ln{\left(\frac{I}{I_0}\right)}\\\\
e^{^{\frac{R\;I}{\eta\;V_T}-\frac{V_\text{CC}}{\eta\;V_T}}} &= \frac{I}{I_0}\\\\
1 &= \frac{I}{I_0}\cdot e^{^{-\frac{R\,I}{\eta\,V_T}+\frac{V_\text{CC}}{\eta\,V_T}}}\\\\
e^{^{-\frac{V_\text{CC}}{\eta\,V_T}}} &= \frac{I}{I_0}\cdot e^{^{-\frac{R\,I}{\eta\,V_T}}}\\\\
\frac{R\,I_0}{\eta\,V_T}\cdot e^{^{-\frac{V_\text{CC}}{\eta\,V_T}}} &= \frac{R\,I}{\eta\,V_T}\cdot e^{^{-\frac{R\,I}{\eta\,V_T}}}\\\\
-\frac{R\,I_0}{\eta\,V_T}\cdot e^{^{-\frac{V_\text{CC}}{\eta\,V_T}}} &= -\frac{R\,I}{\eta\,V_T}\cdot e^{^{-\frac{R\,I}{\eta\,V_T}}}\\\\&\text{set }u=-\frac{R\,I}{\eta\,V_T}\\\\&\therefore\\\\
u\,e^u&=-\frac{R\,I_0}{\eta\,V_T}\cdot e^{^{-\frac{V_\text{CC}}{\eta\,V_T}}}\\\\
u&=\operatorname{LambertW}\left(-\frac{R\,I_0}{\eta\,V_T}\cdot e^{^{-\frac{V_\text{CC}}{\eta\,V_T}}}\right)\\\\
-\frac{R\,I}{\eta\,V_T}&=\operatorname{LambertW}\left(-\frac{R\,I_0}{\eta\,V_T}\cdot e^{^{-\frac{V_\text{CC}}{\eta\,V_T}}}\right)\\\\
I&=-\frac{\eta\,V_T}{R}\cdot\operatorname{LambertW}\left(-\frac{R\,I_0}{\eta\,V_T}\cdot e^{^{-\frac{V_\text{CC}}{\eta\,V_T}}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

There are two obvious branches of LambertW that produce a real number result for $I$. These are $I=2.89494375302447\times 10^{-31}$ and $I=0.378629016951324$.

[Note: Had the correct KVL equation been applied (it wasn't, above), the answer would instead be the main branch's $I=0.322251273110783$.]

Comment: +1. Just two suggestions: name all the constants
(much less typing and easier to follow)
and use $\exp(x)$ instead of $\mathrm{e}^x$.

Comment: @g.kov Thanks. I completely agree about naming the constants. In fact, that's what I did on paper. I wouldn't mind making that adjustment here, though I suppose I may draw from the OP's electronics source for naming. Regarding $e$, I prefer to keep it as that is usually how I see LambertW, in context. See, for example, Wolfram's site on the topic. It would feel wrong to me to use exp.

Comment: @g.kov Variables applied per request. It reads much better to me. The use of $e$ remains, per common usage. For example, at [Wiki LambertW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and at [Wolfram LambertW](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Comment: Of course, this is the matter of taste/habit,
but, as you can see,  
both links do use $\exp$-form, where it results in an easier construction:
$T=\exp \left(\dots\right)$
in "Thermodynamic equilibrium" section of the wiki link,
and Eq.(20) in Wolfram link is $W'(x)=\frac 1{[1+W(x)]\exp[W(x)]}$.

Comment: @g.kov I see that, as well. The way I've proceeded here is more my taste, then. I appreciated your comments. Especially about the use of variables. I hope we can agree it is improved in that sense.

Comment: Yes, it looks much better now.

Comment: @jonk -- thanks. With the correct equations, does it still have two solutions? In practice is the ~0 solution simply ignored, or how does that work?

Comment: @David542 No. With the correct formulation (which I gave you), there is only one real-valued answer on branch 0 (zero) of the product-log function (aka LambertW.) That's as it should be, since it is a circuit. If a circuit had two stable values, then it probably is a bistable circuit and may have negative resistance or some other explanation for that.

Comment: @jonk -- I see, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @David542 In your formulation (which got a sign wrong), the resistance was taken as negative. Which is why two values emerged from the analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Working with whole numbers, the equation write
$$20 x-\frac{273 }{2500}\log (500 x)=7$$ Let $500 x=e^t$ to make
$$\frac{1}{25}e^t-\frac{273 }{2500}t=7$$ and, as said in comments, the solution is given in terms of Lambert function.
$$t=-\frac{2500}{39}-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{100}{273 }e^{-2500/39}\right)\approx 5.24341$$ Back to $x$, this gives $x \approx 0.378629$.

If you do not want to use Lambert function, only numerical methods would give the result. Neglecting the logarithmic term, let us start with $x_0=\frac 7 {20}$ and use Newton method which will give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.3500000000 \\
 1 & 0.3786466187 \\
 2 & 0.3786290170
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: thanks for this answer. A couple questions on this: (1) when you show the Newton method at the bottom, what are you using to get those values: something like matlab, a calculator, or something else? (2) Why do you stipulate "Working with whole numbers..." at the top?

Comment: @David542 : Do you know Newton method for solving nonlinear equations ? I even do it by hand or using a spreasheet or a program of mine or whatever. Whole numbers look nicer and avoid losses of accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

I will do this assuming the constants are exact, but note that $20,7,.002$ each have only one significant figure if they are measured numbers so you should look closely at error propagation. You cannot use the simple linear model we usually do because $0.002$ could be $\pm 25\%$.  I will work to four figures.  First simplify
$$20I - 0.1092  \times \ln{\left(\frac{I}{0.002}\right)} = 7\\
20I-0.1092\ln(I)+0.1092\ln(0.002)=7\\
20I-0.1092\ln(I)=7.678$$
Now logs are slowly varying.  If we ignore the $\ln(I)$ term we have $I=0.3839$ so it screams for fixed point iteration
$$I=\frac 1{20}(7.678+0.1092\ln(I))$$
We start with $I=\frac{6.321}{20}=0.3839$ and iterate to convergence. In three iterations we have $I=0.3786$.

Comment: thanks for this explanation -- but why do you say "It converges" to ~0.3 when the other answers show something closer to ~0.4?

Comment: Because I dropped a sign between the first and second lines.  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I changed the variable $I$ to $x$, then asked [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+20x+-+0.1092%28ln%28x%2F0.002%29%29+%3D+7) to solve your equation, it gave two solutions:

$$x_1 \approx 2.89494 \times {10}^{-31}$$
and
$$x_2 \approx 0.378629.$$

I agree with the others in saying that the problem does not admit an analytic solution.  Only a numerical approximation is possible.